Changing links dynamically for locally hosted wordpress site
I'm hosting an old wordpress site locally with xampp. Most of the links are localhost/wordpress on the machine. When external traffic accesses the site they do it with IPaddress/wordpress.  I've got most of the urls to change dynamically, but there is a page of links that are hardcoded on a page that I can't figure out how to change. The links are listed on a  page and are all localhost/wordpress so when a guest clicks on the link they are directed to a page that says the localhost has refused access.
What's a way to correct this?
I put a php function in the wordpress functions.php for the theme. it went:
function rewrite_links($content){
    if (is_page('name-of-page')) { 
        $home_url = home=url('/');
        $content = str_replace('http://localhost/wordpress', $home_url, $content);
        }
        return $content;
}
add_filter('the content', 'rewrite_links');


If you are hosting the site, and you have a single problem page, isn't the simplest fix to just update the page?

The name of the filter is the_content, not the content.

This was the answer I discovered through ChatGPT and Claude:
function rewrite_asset_urls($url) {
    $server_name = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    if ($server_name !== 'localhost' && $server_name !== '127.0.0.1') {
        $url = str_replace('http://localhost/wordpress', 'http://' . $server_name . '/wordpress', $url);
    }
    return $url;
}

// Apply this function to various WordPress hooks that handle URLs
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_url', 'rewrite_asset_urls');
add_filter('option_siteurl', 'rewrite_asset_urls');
add_filter('option_home', 'rewrite_asset_urls');
add_filter('theme_mod_header_image', 'rewrite_asset_urls');
add_filter('theme_mod_background_image', 'rewrite_asset_urls');
add_filter('style_loader_src', 'rewrite_asset_urls');
add_filter('script_loader_src', 'rewrite_asset_urls');
add_filter('the_content', 'rewrite_asset_urls');
add_filter('widget_text', 'rewrite_asset_urls');

